# MYSQL vs Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to convert a MYSQL query to Laravel's Eloquent format, the MYSQL version returns a value on MySQL Workbench, but the Eloquent version returns a null value with the same request parameters.

here is the MYQSL version of the query

```
 " select
      SUM(
         DATEDIFF(
          if( end_date > $end_date, $end_date, end_date ),
          if( start_date < $start_date, $start_date, start_date )
         ) * child_rate
        )
    from rates where start_date < $end_date and end_date > $start_date


  ";
```

here is the Laravel's Eloquent version

```
$rate_query = "
        SUM(
         DATEDIFF(
          if( end_date > $end_date, $end_date, end_date ),
          if( start_date < $start_date, $start_date, start_date )
         ) * child_rate
        )
       ";

$total_child_rate = DB::table('rates')
                            ->selectRaw(DB::raw($rate_query))
                            ->where('start_date', '<', $end_date)
                            ->where('end_date', '>', $start_date)
                            ->get();
```

what am I not doing right?

`Edited this question to show the answer below`

Correct way of writing a raw query is to wrap the query in a `single qoute`. Below is the solution to the problem after @damask's answer

```
$rate_query = '
        SUM(
         DATEDIFF(
          if( end_date > ?, ?, end_date ),
          if( start_date < ?, ?, start_date )
         ) * child_rate
        )
       ';
        $total_child_rate = DB::table('rates')
                            ->selectRaw(DB::raw($rate_query), [$end_date, $end_date, $start_date, $start_date])
                            ->where('start_date', '<', $end_date)
                            ->where('end_date', '>', $start_date)
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are setting `$rate_query` using double quotes, `$end_date` and `$start_date` are being evaluated as php variables? Try using single quotes, or Nowdoc ?

Comment: I think $end_date and $start_date are php variables that is why he is using it to compare inside if statement.

Comment: yes @damask @Sandeep you guys are correct, I changed the `$rate_query`  to use single quote and I get a value, I'll edit the question to show the correct query

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Telescope to see the query output and compare it with your raw query.